# How to mute a audio sound when an action is tapped?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Adcolony is a video advert platform integrated into Xcode to play ads to users in video and sound,

One of the requirements is to block audio when the add starts playing,

This is the audio:

```
 //Audio Sound On - uncomment
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                  pathForResource:@"soundTrack"
                                  ofType:@"mp3"]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfURL:url
                          error:nil];
```

it starts as soon as the game starts, in view controller,

The triggerVideo action is place in PlayViewController and needs to be set off when ad is triggered,

```
- (IBAction)TriggerVideo:(id)sender {
[AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"ZONE-NUMBER-HERE" withDelegate:nil];
}
```

I've left this aside for a while now, wondering if anyone knows how to employ this function?

Comment: try audioPlayer.volume = 0.0f;

Comment: how do I bring it back after

Comment: audiPlayer.volume = 1.0f

Comment: No where do I put this code?

Comment: set volume to 0 in the delegate methode  - (void) onAdColonyAdStartedInZone:(NSString *)zoneID .... and once it's finished playing ads, it will call the - (void) onAdColonyAdAttemptFinished:(BOOL)shown inZone:(NSString *)zoneID delegate method so place the volume = 1 in that method.

Comment: I can set this up properly! maybe you could write it out properly so I can fix it! And do it in code so I can grant the answer to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these methods to your viewController that's the delegate for adcolony, which should also be the viewcontroller in which you initialize the AVAudioPlayer. I probably don't need to state this, but i'm assuming you have an @Property for your audioPlayer

```
- (void) onAdColonyAdStartedInZone:(NSString *)zoneID{
  self.audioPlayer.volume = 0.0f;
}

- (void) onAdColonyAdAttemptFinished:(BOOL)shown inZone:(NSString *)zoneID{
  self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
}
```